# Issue with MailSlot in winapi, ReadFile doesnt read value from mailslot

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, winapi, c++14

I am trying to set up a mailslot that I can write my values and read from. In my case, I have two processes, which work with each other. The first process gets information from a user and sends the information another process to calculate the result. The second process should read the data from mailslot, but the process was freezing when the function ReadFile() has been called and I get nothing.
I tried to find some information about the mailslot, but I didn't get that I wanted. Who knows about this mailslot and could help me?

The first process:

```
int main()
{
    HANDLE m = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, L"MyMutex");
    if (m == 0)
        return -1;

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    if (CreateProcess(L"c:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Lab3\\Procces1\\Debug\\Procces1.exe", NULL,
        NULL, NULL, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi) == TRUE) {

        bool flagEnd = true;
        double a,b,c;

        HANDLE file = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\mailslot\\c:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Lab3\\mail", GENERIC_WRITE|GENERIC_READ,
            FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
        if (file == 0)
            return -1;

        while (true) {
            WaitForSingleObject(m, INFINITE);
            cout << "Please enter A and B values\n";
            cout << "A = ";
            cin >> a;
            cout << "B = ";
            cin >> b;
            WriteFile(file, &a, sizeof(double), NULL, NULL);
            WriteFile(file, &b, sizeof(double), NULL, NULL);
            ReleaseMutex(m);
        }

        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(m);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Process has not been created\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The second process:

```
int main()
{
    HANDLE mut = OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, L"MyMutex");
    if (mut == 0)
        return -1;

    HANDLE mail = CreateMailslot(L"\\\\.\\mailslot\\c:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Lab3\\mail", 0, MAILSLOT_WAIT_FOREVER, NULL);
    if (mail == 0)
        return -1;

    double a, b, c;
    DWORD byte;
    while (true) {
        WaitForSingleObject(mut, INFINITE);
        cout << "Reading\n"; //this works
        ReadFile(mail, &a, sizeof(double), &byte, NULL);  
        ReadFile(mail, &b, sizeof(double), &byte, NULL);  
        cout << "I have read " << a << " " << b << endl;  //this message doesn't send
        ReleaseMutex(mut);                                //and therefore releasemutex wont be called
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ReadFile` doesn't freeze. It's simply a blocking call when you're passing `nullptr` for the final parameter. Of course, you would be in a much better position to understand your issue, if you used proper error handling. From what I can tell, the only error handling you are using is wrong. This isn't going to be very successful. Start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew).

Comment: `CreateFile/CreateMailslot` on fail return not 0 but `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. so you have incorrect condition. `CreateFile` for mailslot - here you have raise condition - faster of all child process yet not finish (even not begin) call `CreateMailslot`.

Comment: and you not need any mutes here - for what ? what end write data, another read.

Comment: @RbMm It is a task from the university. I understand that this looks strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A note: Use wrong value for error checking. Use `if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)` instead of `if (file == 0)`. (It is suggested to add error checking for all functions call if you haven't done. [`ReadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile#return-value), [`WriteFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile#return-value), etc.)

And remove the `Procces1.exe` (I didn't see its usage here) part. Start the second process (create and read Mailslot process) first, then start the first process (write mailslot process), it works and get the following result:

[image]

[image]

Edited code:

The first process:

```
int main()
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    HANDLE m = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, L"MyMutex");
    if (m == 0)
        return -1;

    bool flagEnd = true;
    double a, b, c;

    HANDLE file = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\mailslot\\c:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Lab3\\mail", GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return -1;

    while (true) {
        cout << "Please enter A and B values\n";
        cout << "A = ";
        cin >> a;
        cout << "B = ";
        cin >> b;
        WriteFile(file, &a, sizeof(double), NULL, NULL);
        WriteFile(file, &b, sizeof(double), NULL, NULL);
        ReleaseMutex(m);
    }

    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(m);

    return 0;
}
```

The second process:

```
int main()
{
    HANDLE mail = CreateMailslot(L"\\\\.\\mailslot\\c:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Lab3\\mail", 0, MAILSLOT_WAIT_FOREVER, NULL);
    if (mail == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return -1;

    HANDLE mut = NULL;

    cout << "Waiting for another process write something to mailslot\n"; //this works
    while (NULL == mut)
    {
        mut = OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, L"MyMutex");
        Sleep(10);
        cout << ".";
    }
    cout << "\n";

    double a, b, c;
    DWORD byte;
    while (true) {
        WaitForSingleObject(mut, INFINITE);
        cout << "Reading\n"; //this works
        ReadFile(mail, &a, sizeof(double), &byte, NULL);
        ReadFile(mail, &b, sizeof(double), &byte, NULL);
        cout << "I have read " << a << " " << b << endl;  //this message doesn't send
    }
    return 0;
}
```

More reference: official sample for "[Reading from a Mailslot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/reading-from-a-mailslot)" and "[Writing to a Mailslot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/writing-to-a-mailslot)".

Comment: Your answer is awesome! But now mutex does not work :( I can't delete procces1 and mutex this is a task from my university. My knowledge of c++ is very poor, I prefer another language.

Comment: @Saliery I've added mutex you can have a try.